# How do I replace an element in an array if its key matches the key of another array?

Tags: php

I have two txt files with the same length (10 lines in each). One file has IDs, and the other has a "rating" (0, 1, 2, etc) that is associated with each ID. For example:

txt 1 | txt 2
123 | 1
234 | 2
etc.

I want to replace the rating when I provide an ID.

What I did was search the key associated with the provided ID and when it matches the key in the ratings array I replace the corresponding value in the ratings array.

So the idea is **find key for '123' in ids (key=0) and replace the rating value with key=0 (in this case 1) for another value**.

I have the following in a function:

```
public function updateRating($disease, $id, $rating){
    $filename = $disease.".txt";
    $filename_2 = $disease."Ratings.txt";
    $ids = file($filename);
    $ratings = file($filename_2);

    $index_ids = array_keys($ids, $id."\n");
    $index_ratings = array_keys($ratings);

    $size = count($ids);

    for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++){
        if($index_ratings[$i] == $index_ids){
            $ratings = str_replace($ratings[$i], $rating."\n", $ratings);
        }
    }

    $ratings_n = implode("", $ratings);
    file_put_contents($filename_2, $ratings_n);
    return array("debug2" => $index_ids, "debug3" => $index_ratings, "debug4" => $ratings);
```

The index_ids (the key for the provided ID) is being returned correctly, but the array for the ratings ($ratings) is returned as if nothing was replaced. What is wrong in this code and how can I correct it to do what I want it to do?

Comment: Please simply your question

Comment: I have two arrays. I search the key of a certain value in array 1. When this key matches a key in array 2, I want to replace the corresponding value in array 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_search() in your function to get the key:

https://paiza.io/projects/zdg_xzGwV8KfgOqkzeCgjA

```
function replaceValue($value, $arr1, &$arr2){
    $key = array_search($value, $arr1);
    if($key === false){
        return false;
    }else{
        $arr2[$key] = $value;
        return true;
    }
}

if(replaceValue("baz", $arr1, $arr2)){
    print_r($arr2);
}else{
    echo "no match found";
}

Result:

Array
(
    [x] => bizz
    [y] => bazz
    [c] => baz
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually the keys are the same for both arrays. What I need is to change the value of array 2 given the value of array 1. So I have `$arr1 = [0 => '123', 1 => '234']` and `$arr2 = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']`. If I provide '123' (key=0), I want to change 'a' (key=0).

Comment: @mfs My code will also work to replace every single matching key. Do you just want to take a key and value and update array 2 like in a function, or loop through array 1 and replace all instances?

Comment: This will not work as both the indexes for the arrays are consirded to be same.

Comment: @symlink I don't want to replace every single matching key because all keys match. What I want is to give a function a value of array 1 and change the value of array 2 with the same key. If I have `$arr1 = [0 => '123', 1 => '234']` and `$arr2 = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']` and I give the function `123`, it will replace `a` with whatever I want.

Comment: @KunalRaut what will not work? Click the link and see for yourself that it works...

Comment: @mfs so it finds the key that matches the value in array 1 and replaces that key's value in array 2?

Comment: Your answer and what else

Comment: @KunalRaut You're not making any sense at all.

Comment: @symlink yes, exactly!

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this kind of steps to achieve the result

```
<?php
$arr1 = [0 => '123', 1 => '234'];
$arr2 = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b'];


for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr1) ; $i++) { 
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr1) ; $i++) { 
        if ($arr1[$i] == '123') {
            $arr2[$i] = 'abc';          
        }
    }
}
echo'<pre>';
print_r($arr2);
echo '<pre>';
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => b
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but actually what I have is the opposite: the keys are the same but the values are different. So I have `$arr1 = [0 => '123', 1 => '234']` and `$arr2 = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']`. If I provide '123' (key=0), I want to change 'a' (key=0).

Comment: Yes it will work for it too you can try if you want to

Comment: This code will replace all matching keys and that is not what I want because all keys match! The keys for arr1 are 0, 1, 2,... and for arr2 too. So there needs to be a condition that it will only replace when the value in arr1 is what I want: `$arr1 = [0 => '123', 1 => '234']` and `$arr2 = [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']`. If I give to the function '123' it should replace only 'a'.

Comment: @mfs Do check out my edited answer i came up with easy and small code.